# reading binary data in MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab

I am trying to read binary data using Matlab but when I wrote the code, and the data I have is not right.

The binary file is written:

```
ofstream outfile2 (outfilename2.c_str() , ofstream::binary);
...
vector<complex<double> > Cxy(2560);
... // data collected from the device.
    for(unsigned j = 0; j < 2560; j++)
    {
        outfile2.write((const char*)&Cxy[j], sizeof(Cxy[j]));
        outfile2.flush();
    }
```

when I read the data using:

```
double fft_len = 256*10;
  std::vector<std::complex<double> > vtr(fft_len);
  vtr.resize(fft_len);
  {
     std::ifstream input("data.bin", std::ifstream::binary);
     for (int i=0; i< fft_len; ++i)
          input.read((char *)&vtr[i],sizeof(vtr[i]));
  }
     for (size_t i=0; i<vtr.size(); ++i)
          std::cout << vtr[i] << endl; // data look like:       //(1.31649816e+07,3.97112323e+06)
```

I used copy & paste data into matlab, then plot it out.

I also want to try different way to read data by using Matlab directly:
filename = 'data.bin';

```
fid = fopen(filename);

fseek(fid,4*2560,'bof');

y = fread(fid,[2,inf],'long');

x = complex(y(1,:),y(2,:));

plot(abs(x));

figure, plot(abs(x));
```

but the length of x only 104 but not 2560 as I expected.

So any one can help?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Why are you seeking into the file before reading it?

Comment: @Suever because there are some "(",  "," , ")" between those values

Comment: But you're seeking right past your data and then trying to read in what's left of the file.

Comment: @Suever so, what should I do now? can you give me more detail? Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you just remove the `fseek` call?

Comment: @Suever I already tried that waym but still give me wrong data.